# HTML "style" tag doesn't work

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I tried the following code in both online editor in w3schools & pen editor in codepen. Here is that code.

```css
body {
 background-color: lavenderblush
}
.red-text {
  color: red;
}
h1 {
  font-family: Tangerine, times new roman;
  font-size: 55px;
}
p {
  font-size : 18px;
  font-family: inconsolata;
} 
.thick-salmon-border {
  border-color: salmon;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.smaller-image {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.thick-royalblue-border {
  border-color: royalblue;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.thick-green-border {
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.thick-sandybrown-border {
  border-color: sandybrown;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.thick-lightpink-border {
  border-color: lightpink;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.thick-rosybrown-border {
  border-color: rosybrown;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rosybrown;
  border-width: 5px;
}
 .AntiqueWhite-box {
  background-color: AntiqueWhite;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
 .MistyRose-box {
  background-color: MistyRose;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rancho&effect=shadow-multiple">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata">
<h1 class="red-text font-effect-shadow-multiple">My Favorite Songs</h1>
<p>
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_Sheeran"><img class="smaller-image thick-salmon-border" src="http://cdn3.thr.com/sites/default/files/2015/07/ed_sheeran.jpg" alt="My Favorite Songs"></a>
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_You"><img class="smaller-image thick-royalblue-border" src="https://images.genius.com/fc44439c55552eb23d4a9ecb28a21f06.1000x1000x1.jpg " alt="My Favorite Songs"></a>
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinking_Out_Loud"><img class="smaller-image thick-green-border" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ad/X_cover.png" alt="My Favorite Songs"></a>
</p>
<div class=" box AntiqueWhite-box">
    <p>Ed Sheeran</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Ed-Sheeran/Shape-of-You">Shape of You</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Ed-Sheeran/Thinking-Out-Loud">Thinking Out Loud</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Ed-Sheeran/Galway-Girl">Galway Girl</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form action="/submit-Ed Sheeran" id="Ed Sheeran-form">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="reaction" checked>Like</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="reaction">Dislike</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="reaction">None of Above</label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="electronic devices" checked>Phone</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="electronic devices">Laptop</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="electronic devices">Mp3</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ed Sheeran URL">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
<p>
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele"><img class="smaller-image thick-sandybrown-border" src="http://www.hellomagazine.com/imagenes//celebrities/2017080741334/adele-grenfell-tower-victims-screening/0-214-739/adele-t.jpg" alt="My Favorite Songs"></a>
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_in_the_Deep"><img class="smaller-image thick-lightpink-border" src="http://netstorage.metrolyrics.com/albums/2777347adele-21.jpg" alt="My Favorite Songs"></a>
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_(Adele_song)"><img class="smaller-image thick-rosybrown-border" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a9/95/9c/a9959c17c8260650136fdc4a7d8bb218--adele-in-concert-adele--album.jpg" alt="My Favorite Songs"></a>
    <p>
        <div class="box MistyRose-box">
            <p>Adele</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Adele-3/Rolling-in-the-Deep">Rolling In the Deep</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Adele-3/Someone-Like-You">Someone Like You</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Adele-3/Hello">Hello</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form action="/submit-Adele" id="Adele">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="reaction" checked>Like</label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="reaction">Dislike</label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="reaction">None of Above</label>
                <br>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="electronic devices" checked>Phone</label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="electronic devices">Laptop</label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="electronic devices">Mp3</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Adele URL">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

BTW, I ran this in "Edge" browser in windows. What's wrong?
This code worked fine until yesterday, but now css doesn't work. Did something change in w3schools or codepen? Is there a type-o? Please help.

Comment: It works correctly in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fxmea0m8/

Comment: I see your very short answer was deleted!  Sorry about that, but, could you post a slightly longer explanation of where the 'invisible' character was, so that this question might help someone in future?  You can then accept your answer which marks the question as 'case closed'.

Answer (score 3):

**First** : Use head taq(required):

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

    </style>
</head>
```

**Second** : Use style code like this (not required) :

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

</style>
```

**Third** : Put `;` in end of your css code(in end of line 6) (not required):

```
 body {
   background-color: lavenderblush;
  }
```

I hope  **second** and **third** help you .

**:)**

Answer (score 0):

It's working correctly on my side in codepen.

you should try to hard refresh(ctrl+F5)

OR

Clear cache and cookies then load the page

OR

Try a hardcore versioning e.g. add `?1` or any thing after `?` in URL and then hit URL.
e.g.

```
http://<your URL>.html?1
```

The best practice is to use styles and scripts in `<head >` tag as it'll be loaded before the page and you'll see the design at its best. If it doesn't get solved then above solution will work if it's cache related issue.

> Use `Style` in `<head>`

Comment: i think he had head taq but don't write here!

Answer (score 0):

It might be a hunch, but you said it worked until yesterday. Try clearing your 
browser cache.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10607/microsoft-edge-view-delete-browser-history
Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

You mistake is a semicolon in your body tag background-color property

```
 body{
   background-color: lavenderblush;
  }
```